# I'm using the following C code

Tags: c, function, return, printf, declaration

```
float pie = 3.14;


int main()
{   
 float r,res;
 printf("Enter radius value\n");
 scanf("%f", &r);

  res=area( r );
  printf("Area = %f\n",res);
 //printf("Circumference =  %f\n", circum( r ));
}

float area( float r )
{
 return pie * r * r;
}
```

I'm getting error as conflicting types for 'area' and previous implicit declaration of 'area' was here,But this code works fine if i changed to integer

In IDE it works fine if i changed that code to integer float pie = 3.14;

```
    int main() {
    int r,res; 
    printf("Enter radius value\n"); 
    scanf("%d", &r); res=area( r ); 
    printf("Area = %d\n",res); 
     } 
    int area( int r )
     { 

return pie * r * r;
 }
```

without declaration it works fine for integer but for floating point numbers i am getting error why?

Comment: In the absence of a forward declaration, the return type of a function is implicitly taken to be `int`.  But it's bad practice to rely on that.  Just add a proper forward declaration *before* the function that calls it:  `float area(float r);`

Comment: See the linked question.  The problem is that you have defined your function `area()` after main and provided no other declaration before main.  Just move the whole function before main and it should work.

Comment: BTW: it's `PI` not `PIE`. A pie is something the serve you in English pubs.

Comment: @MichaelWalz but PI != 3.14 ;)

Comment: @AlfieJ.Palmer yep, but it's still better than `22./7.` which I've seen in some code recently ;-)

Comment: In addition, you shouldn't be using a dinosaur compiler. Use a standard C compiler instead.

Answer (score 1):

C allows implicit function declaration, so because you didn't give an explicit function declaration prior to calling it for the first time, it's implicitly declared with this prototype:

```
int area(); // Implicit arguments
```

And later when you give a real declaration, they're conflict.

If you want the function to return an actual floating point number, **give a forward declaration**:

```
float area(float);
```

Add the above line before `int main()` and the problam is solved.

By the way, implicit function declaration is removed as of C11 standard (ISO/IEC 9899:2011).

Comment: In IDE it works fine if i changed that code to integer 


float pie = 3.14;

 
 int main()
 { 
  int r,res;
  printf("Enter radius value\n");
  scanf("%d", &r);

   res=area( r );
   printf("Area = %d\n",res);
  //printf("Circumference =  %f\n", circum( r ));
 }

 int area( int r )
 {
  return pie * r * r;
 }
without declaration it works fine for integer but for floating point numbers  i am getting error why?

Comment: @Poornima Solution added.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are using a common term or a variable all over the program 
like you did here

```
float pie = 3.14
```

write this instead

```
#define pie 3.14 //this is a macro
```

and coming to your error ,
whenever you are using a function, you have to provide a explicit declaration of it or in other words prototype of it. 
Type this on top of your C file

```
float area(float r)
```

or

```
float area(float)
```

And if you feel lazy then use your function before your main function instead using it after you main function.

Answer (score -1):

You should do function call after function defination.Otherwise declar function in header file and use it.